# How do I set constant state variables in source code before migrating to a test network?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Is there a way to change the value of address literals in solidity source code before migrating to a local test chain using Truffle? Currently, if a contract A needs to know the address of another contract B, you must pass B's address to A's constructor, which means the address must be stored as a state variable in A's storage. This is very expensive, costing 20,000 gas for initialization plus 200 gas for every read. Ideally B's address could be stored in A as a *constant* state variable, but constant's cannot be set in a constructor, only hardcoded into the source code.

For example, here, creation of C uses 20,000 more gas than D. And D's get() can be `pure` rather than `view`. I'd like to be able to change D's value of `a` before compiling and migrating to a test network.

```
contract C {
    address a;
    constructor(address _a) public {
        a = _a;
    }

    function get() external view returns (address) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

```
contract D {
    address constant a = 0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111;

    function get() external pure returns (address) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question. Of course you can change the source code before compiling it... are you asking about how to automate such a process? Or maybe whether Truffle has some built-in mechanism for doing so?

Comment: A little perspective. You would opt for the variable if you want configuration. A quick check at ethgasstation suggests it adds USD $0.003 to the one-time release cost, assuming you would only migrate to mainnet one time. Admittedly more if you also for fast confirmation. Still, I wouldn't call that "very expensive" or compromise my process over that. As a heuristic, I would concentrate on optimizing user-facing functions and making sure costs are scale-invariant.

Comment: @smarx yes I would like to know if truffle has anything built-in doe this

Comment: Rob, it would save 200 gas each call to get() since it doesn't have to do an SLOAD plus maybe some other benefits of having a getter that's pure. And sure it's only $0.003 but in some cases that's 20% the cost of deploying a contract! And if a user is expected to pay the cost of contract creation, which is true in my case, it's a user-facing issue.

Comment: The project I'm working on creates many small contracts that all need to be initialized with a couple unchanging address

Comment: So in other words, in my situation, the cost is proportional to the number of users

Comment: If you were a client I would explore the goals and constraints with a mind to optimizing the architecture. To answer your earlier question directly, truffle does not have such a thing but truffle isn't relevant in the case that users are deploying contracts from your templates. You may have heard of libraries and something similar but I don't think it applies here.

Comment: Your only option is to write a script which auto-generates this contract, compiles it and deploys it. I would note, yet again (as you've been noted previously), that: 1. A **one-time** cost of 20000 gas is nothing. 2. The `get` function can be called only once, since this address is not going to change according to your contract, so the cost of this **one-time** operation is - again - nothing (even more nothing).

Comment: The real cost would be calling external functions of `A` contract inside `C` and `D` contracts. I assume that those exist even though you haven't posted them. So in short, it sounds like you are focusing your optimization efforts in the wrong direction.

Comment: I'll probably end up doing something custom like goodvibration suggests. In production, the addresses never have to change so I'll just hard code them in as constants but for testing I'll figure something out.

Comment: For clarity, I should mention that I have a factory contract creating many instances of a very small contract (which would all need two initializations). Not that it changes the issue at all

Comment: The solidity devs seem to agree that this cost isn't totally negligible https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3356